# symfony 1.4 build-schema id causing problems for views

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

All of a sudden I'm having problems with executing a view via Propel.

```
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'view_total_count_for_collection.ID' in 'field list']
```

Well, DUH. That's because there is no actual ID column in the view! So why have you built a model around a non-existant column?

Here's the relevant section of my schema.yml, generated by propel:build-schema

```
  view_total_count_for_collection:
    _attributes: { phpName: ViewTotalCountForCollection }
    collection_id: { phpName: CollectionId, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true }
    asset_count: { phpName: AssetCount, type: BIGINT, size: '21', required: true, defaultValue: '0' }
    pallet_received: { phpName: PalletReceived, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: false }
    case_received: { phpName: CaseReceived, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: false }
    unit_received: { phpName: UnitReceived, type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: false }
    total_pallets_for_asset: { phpName: TotalPalletsForAsset, type: DECIMAL, size: '32', scale: '0', required: false }
    total_cases_for_asset: { phpName: TotalCasesForAsset, type: DECIMAL, size: '41', scale: '0', required: false }
    total_units_for_asset: { phpName: TotalUnitsForAsset, type: DECIMAL, size: '41', scale: '0', required: false }
```

This is all fine, as far as I'm concerned. Other views seem to have a magical Id field declared, and have been working fine, and further research tells me that this is just what Propel does. It hasn't been a problem before.

However, now all of a sudden it's causing a problem. And I don't understand why. Can anyone help me to resolve this? So why does THIS particular definition in schema.yml NOT have an ID? And why would I need to suddenly have one anyway?

Comment: I seem to have 'resolved' the problem by adding "primaryKey: true" to the "collection_id" definition, which is the target of my GROUP BY in the view. Doesn't explain WHY though, so I'd appreciate any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

set primary key

not setting primary key default column is "id"